# Integral homomorphisms induce closed maps

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, solution-verification

Let $f:A\to B$ be an integral homomorphism of rings. I shall prove that the induced map $f^*$ between the spectra is closed.

If $J\subseteq B$ is an ideal, set $I:=f^{-1}(J)$. $f$ induces a well defined homomorphism $A/I\to B/J$, injective and integral. For any prime ideal $p\subset A/I$ exists a prime ideal $q\subset B/J$ such its contraction is $p$; since the following diagram commutes, $\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
\operatorname {Spec}(B/J)@>>>\operatorname {Spec}(A/I)\\
@VVV @VVV\\
\operatorname {Spec}(B) @>>> \operatorname {Spec}(A)
\end{CD}
this means that for any prime ideal $I\subseteq P\subset A$ there is a prime ideal $J\subseteq Q\subset B$ whose contraction is $P$. This allows to prove $f^*V(J)=V(I)$: in fact the $\subseteq$ direction is trivial, while the other direction is the assertion above. Did I forget to check anything?

Comment: You want to use the Lying Over theorem. Have you? In general it is false you can find Q that contracts to P. The commutativity of the diagram does not say this.

Comment: I'm using the theorem 5.1 of Atiyah-Macdonald, it says that an integral injection of rings induces a surjective map between the spectra. However I use it on $A/I,B/J$, and that commutative diagram translates the result to $A,B$

Comment: Okay. You never mention that theorem in your post.